# createGlobalMarker() doesn't create a marker in Vector CANoe in Offline Mode

Tags: capl, canoe

I wrote a basic CAPL program and included it as programming node in a CANoe measurement configuration.

The node will check the content of a specific message and create a Global Marker via `createGlobalMarker()` if the conditions are met. A `write()` statement ensures that the code portion is being executed. The CANoe configuration is being used in offline mode (I don't have a licence on this machine, no vector nodes are attached, I just want to replay stuff and check it out).

In the graphics window, no marker is created. No warnings are present in the write window. Here is the code mockup:

```
on linframe myFrame
{
    output(this)
    if( /* some condition */ )
    {
        write("code being executed");
        createGlobalMarker("A","test");   // in actual code, the name is dynamic to avoid forbidden name duplicates
    }
}
```

From the docs,

> Sets a marker in CANoe Trace Window, Graphics Window and State
> Tracker. The set marker can be displayed with the shortcut menu Show
> in the marker bar of these windows.

So I would naturally expect to see the markers. I can create one manually from the Graphics window, and that one is displayed. I can't find the shortcut menu being referred to.

The marker bar is visible in the Graphics window and I can create a new marker by double-clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

The markers are added whenever the function `createGlobalMarker()` is triggered.
To view the markers in the Trace Window, it has to be in chronological mode.
Now, to view the marker created by your code, you have to right-click on the marker area (grey bar) to bring up the shortcut menu and select "**Show > A**" or "**Show All**". This will show the markers which your code has generated (with a lock symbol in graphics window).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is "chronological mode"? I'm not familiar with the term in CANoe.

Comment: In the Trace Window, the 11th icon on the top left is the "chronological mode". The tooltip for this button is "Toggle display mode".
When activated, all the CAN frames are shown. When deactivated, only the latest CAN frames are shown.

Comment: But I want this in the Graphics window, not in the Trace window.

Comment: Once the markers are added in any way (either by code or manually), you can go to the graphics window, right-click on the "Marker Bar" (the grey line just below the graph) and select "Show All".